# Using pySpark to consume data from Kafka Application

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I am new to Apache Kafka and Pyspark.

I am using a python script to get data from reddit API and put those data into kafka topics.
Now I am trying to write a pyspark script to get data from kafka brokers. However, I kept facing the same problem:

```
23/04/12 15:20:13 WARN ClientUtils$: Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 38 for topics [Set(DWD_TOP_LOG, DWD_CONTROVERSIAL_LOG, DWD_NEW_LOG, DWD_HOT_LOG)] from broker [id:2,host:kafka-2,port:29093] failed
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
    at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
    at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:93)
    at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:66)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:60)
```

The kafka application I setup in docker container with zookeeper as follow:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
```

And in my pyspark script

```
kafka_params = {
    "zookeeper.connect": "localhost:2181",  # Update this with your Zookeeper host and port
    "group.id": "reddit-sentiment-group",
    "auto.offset.reset": "smallest"
}

kafka_stream = KafkaUtils.createStream(
    ssc,
    kafka_params["zookeeper.connect"],
    kafka_params["group.id"],
    {topic: 1 for topic in kafka_topics}
)
```

Using spark-submit

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.4.5 test4.py
```

I've also tried using KafkaUtil.createDirectStream and using kafka brokers: localhost:9092
But also had the same error.

If anyone can provide any suggestion or direction that would be great!
Thank you

Comment: 1) you're missing Kafka from your compose file. Zookeeper doesn't hold topic data 2) You should be using Spark **Structured** Streaming, as the other is deprecated, and connecting to kafka instead of Zookeeper